# Error on How to SUM up all the rows of a column by Query and PHP.

Tags: php, mysql

Here I am trying to add all the columns up from one table echo out the result.

I have a table with Points that have been recorded by user, every points gets added I would like to add it up and print it out as result for the users score.

I am getting an error where the SUM Query is run. and the result is 0.

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
    // see if the form has been completed
    include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
    //include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    // Initialize any variables that the page might echo
    $username = "";
    $weight = "";
    $weighthist = "";
    $id = "";       

    if(isset($_GET["u"])){
        $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT users.*, weighthistory.* FROM users JOIN weighthistory USING(id)";

    $user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);


    // check if the user exists in the database
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $row ["id"];
        $username = $row ["username"];
        $weight = $row["weight"];
        $weighthist = $row["weighthist"];
        $point_hist = $row["point_hist"];

        }

        // this is to calculate points score
        $calweight = $weight - $weighthist;     
        $points = $calweight * 10;

        $result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM (point_hist) AS value_sum FROM points_history'); 
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
        $sum = $row['value_sum'];


?>
```

THIS IS THE HTML:

```
    <div><b>Point Hist: </b> <?php echo $sum; ?> </div>
    <input id="point_hist" type="hidden" name="point_hist" value="<?php echo $sum; ?>" readonly/>

</html>
```

Comment: For one, you mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: @AmalMurali Can you please help me with the code. as I am very new to mysql and mysqli

Comment: @user3311898 You can either use `mysql_*` **OR** `mysqli_*` **OR** `PDO` but not randomly cycle b/w them in the same file.

Comment: Adding to what @hjpotter92 said, you need to pick one *and it should **not** be `mysql_*`, which is deprecated*.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, thanks for the tips here is the final result of my query etc...
`$res = mysqli_query($db_conx,'SELECT sum(point_hist) FROM points_history');`
`if (FALSE === $res) die("Select sum failed: ".mysqli_error);`
`$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);`
`$sum = $row[0];`